# Azure Static Web App + App Service Node API + Mobile App?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, azure-static-web-app, msal-react

Is it possible to link a Azure SWA to App Service API and also use MSAL in a mobile app (react native) to authenticate and call the same App Service API? I have tried but cannot get it working. Do I have to skip the linking part and just use MSAL in both my SWA frontend and React Native Mobile App?

Answer (score 0):

Under the API blade of your Static Web App, you should be able to link an existing [web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-app-service) as an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/add-api?tabs=react). Existing resource types are function apps, web apps, container apps, and APIM. Any backend requests should be forwarded to the link resource when you use `/api` and are fully authenticated through this link. Confirm your app service as static web app provider under the Authorization blade and [only your static web app should be able to access it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/functions-bring-your-own#security-constraints).

After confirming authentication between your static web app and web app, then add additional identity provider to the app service for your mobile app

Comment: I understand the steps you laid out here. The link between my SWA and App Service worked fine.
You're telling me I need to add additional identity provider to the App Service for the mobile app, but I want to use Microsoft AD also as identity provider for my mobile app.
I'm pretty sure I tried every possible solution to get it working but everything just gave me unauthorized 401.

I have now completely scrapped the linked authentication and /api, and completely moved to use MSAL for the SWA, passport-azure-ad for my NodeJS App Service and react-native-app-auth for the RN mobile App.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I was stating after you confirming authentication was correct on your SWA, then add Micrsoft as the identity provider of your API app service. When users authenticate with your mobile and SWA, you're passing the authenticated token to your API similar to this [end-to-end tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux).